# Value of the following limit

Tags: limits

I'm just a high school math student who was writing a paper on a new type of probability but I got stuck here because even the teachers who taught me were lost as to what the value of this would be. As long as the calculator could allow me, I got the answer to be 0.288788. I actually wanted to know what was the derivation of this rather than just a numeric value, for example could it be something like $\frac{1}{e^2}$ or any number which was rather peculiar.
$$ 
=\frac{(2^1-1)(2^2-1)(2^3-1)(2^4-1)...(2^n-1)}{2^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}}
$$
What will be the limit as n tends to $\infty$

In retrospect the question can also be written as
$$
\lim_{i \to \infty}\Pi_{n=1}^i \frac{2^{n}-1}{2^n}
$$
Your help would be very much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Did you type this correctly?  as it stands, the numerator clearly goes to $\infty$ but the denominator just goes to $2$.

Comment: Reverse engineering  your numerical  result, I expect you really  intended to ask about the infinite product $\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}(1-2^{-i})$, which can be computed using the [Pochhammer Symbol](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html), as [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=product%5B%281-2%5E%28-n%29%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2Cinfinity%7D%5D)

Comment: I am really sorry, I kinda messed up my latex equation. I just corrected it right now, can you look at it right now? Thank you alotttttt

Comment: No worries.  Yes, post edit I see that my guess was correct.  You are indeed after an instance of the Pochhammer symbol.  You can certainly read about that online...unless I am missing something, there is no simple combination of familiar constants that does the job here.  [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol) is an article that discusses some relevant infinite products.

Comment: Thank you so much, your help is really appreciated.

Comment: [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PochhammerSymbol.html) is another reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^{n}-1}{2^n}=\prod_{n=1}^p \frac{2^{n}-1}{2^n} \prod_{n=p+1}^\infty \frac{2^{n}-1}{2^n}$$
$$y=\prod_{n=p+1}^\infty \frac{2^{n}-1}{2^n}\implies \log(y)=\sum_{n=p+1}^\infty \log \left(1-2^{-n}\right)$$ Using Taylor expansion we have
$$\log(1-2^{-n})=-x-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}-\frac{x^5}{5}-\frac{x^6}{6}+O\left(x^7\right)$$ with $x=2^{-n}$.

This gives
$$\log(1-2^{-n})=-\frac{1}{60} a^{-6 n} \left(10+12a^n+15 a^{2 n}+20 a^{3 n}+30 a^{4 n}+60 a^{5 n}\right)$$ with $a=2$. So we have geometric series. Using $p=5$ and summing, this will give
$$\log(y)=-\frac{1976285950427}{62910533468160}$$ and then
$$\frac{9765}{32768}\times e^{\log(y)} \sim 0.288788095086612$$

The "exact" value is
$$0.28878809508660242127889972192923078008891190484069\cdots$$

**Edit**

Making the problem more general for
$$z_a=\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a^{n}-1}{a^n}\implies \log(z_a)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log \left(1-a^{-n}\right)$$ and switching the order of summation, we have
$$\log(z_a)=-\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{a^{-k}}{k \left(1-a^{-k}\right)}$$ For $a=2$,this will give
$$\log(z_2)=-\Big[1+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{21}+\frac{1}{60}+\frac{1}{155}+\frac{1}{378}+\frac{1}
   {889}+\frac{1}{2040}+\frac{1}{4599}+\frac{1}{10230}+\frac{1}{22517}+\frac{1}{49140}+\frac{1}{106483}+\frac{1}{229362}+\frac{1}{4
   91505}+\frac{1}{1048560}+\frac{1}{2228207}+\frac{1}{4718574},\frac{1}{9961453}+\frac
   {1}{20971500}+\frac{1}{44040171}+\frac{1}{92274666}+\frac{1}{192937961}+\frac{1
   }{402653160}+\frac{1}{838860775}+\frac{1}{1744830438}+\cdots   \Big]$$ Limited to these only terms, this would give
$$\log(z_2)=-1.24206209427900$$ Taking the exponential and computing, this  would give as an approximation
$$z_2=0.28878809524064630741$$

As a function of $a$, we then generate the following constants
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
a & z_a \\
 2 & 0.2887880950866024212788997 \\
 3 & 0.5601260779279489449697922 \\
 4 & 0.6885375371203397154565144 \\
 5 & 0.7603327958712324201014883 \\
 6 & 0.8056877281621649409237502 \\
 7 & 0.8367954070890378710267298 \\
 8 & 0.8594059944007028662007586 \\
 9 & 0.8765603540359642058360198 \\
 10 & 0.8900100999989990000001000
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

We can simplify the log of the product using a number theoretic function:
$$
\begin{align}
-\log\left(\prod_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2^n-1}{2^n}\right)
&=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\log\left(1-2^{-n}\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{2^{-kn}}{k}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{d\mid n}\frac{2^{-n}}d\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sigma_1(n)}{n}\,2^{-n}
\end{align}
$$
where $\sigma_1(n)$ is the sum of all of the divisors of $n$.

This removes the need to compute logarithms; however, it still requires computing an exponential to get the final product.

This also works for the generalization proposed by Claude Leibovici if we change all the $2$'s to $a$'s.